# What indexes would I create for a query like this?

Tags: postgresql, index

Here's a query I've got:

```
SELECT "balance_transactions"."fee"
FROM "balance_transactions" 
JOIN charges ON balance_transactions.source = charges.balance_id 
WHERE "balance_transactions"."account_id" = 123 
AND (balance_transactions.type = 'charge' 
AND charges.refunded = false 
AND charges.invoice IS NOT NULL) 
AND ("balance_transactions"."created" BETWEEN '2013-12-29' AND '2014-01-28');
```

What's hurting my brain is figuring out what I need to index to optimize a query like this.

Would I create individual indexes on each column in that WHERE statement? Or a single index that encompasses multiple columns? Or something else?

I happen to be using Postgres.

Here's the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=40.44..9294.43 rows=744 width=4) (actual time=0.791..32.687 rows=1131 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on balance_transactions  (cost=40.02..2266.08 rows=1023 width=22) (actual time=0.737..1.006 rows=1201 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((account_id = 79) AND ((type)::text = 'charge'::text) AND (created >= '2013-12-29 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created <= '2014-01-28 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_balance_transactions_account_type_created  (cost=0.00..39.77 rows=1023 width=0) (actual time=0.716..0.716 rows=1201 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((account_id = 79) AND ((type)::text = 'charge'::text) AND (created >= '2013-12-29 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created <= '2014-01-28 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
   ->  Index Scan using index_stripe_charges_on_stripe_id on charges  (cost=0.42..6.86 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=1 loops=1201)
         Index Cond: ((balance_id)::text = (balance_transactions.source)::text)
         Filter: ((NOT refunded) AND (invoice IS NOT NULL))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 0
 Total runtime: 32.924 ms
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Generally it is advised that we create indexes for all fields after where clause.

Comment: Run explain plan on your query and include that in your question along with the version of Postgres your on.

Comment: @JustBob Updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following two indexes:

```
charges(balance_id, refunded, invoice)
balance_transactions(account_id, type, created, source, fee)
```

The first is a covering index for `charges`.  The index should be used for the query with no need for the data tables.

The second is a covering index for `balance_transactions`.  The first three will satisfy the `where` clause.  The four column will be used for the `join` and the final is needed for the `select`.

Comment: Depending on data volume and data distribution would a filtered indexed have any value here?

Comment: @JustBob . . . Of course, it *could*.  My interpretation of the query is that any account could be chosen (for example), so I don't see the advantage of a filtered index.